# Proper way to call a GUI in Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I was wondering if there is a standard way to call a GUI method. For example, I could create a class called GUI and use constructor to create new GUI and view the user interface. Or I could create a public static method inside GUI class and call it from the main. I would like to know if there is right or wrong way of doing it. Or you could specify how you prefer it yourself.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it GUI specific? Or are you referring to "use a constructor or a static method to create new instances" in general?

Comment: yes GUI specific. I'm only curious because you can do it in several different ways. Just would like to know if there is a standard or recommended path I should follow.

Answer (score 2):

For myself I have the following solution based on [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), which - in my mind - is clear and provides a quite good overview.

The GUI itself is defined in the class `GUI` inside the package `view` and may look like the following:

```
package view;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import controller.GameController;

public class GUI extends JFrame {
    // A controller class
    private GameController gameController;

    public GUI(String title, GameController gameController) {
        super(title);

        setSize(600, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        this.gameController = gameController;
    }
}
```

Now I have the class `Main` in the package `controller`, which initialise the GUI and set it visible:

```
package manager;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import view.GUI;
import controller.GameController;

public class Main {
    private static GUI gui;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                gui = new GUI("Title", new GameController());
                gui.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This works well for me. With `gameController` you might now interact with this controller class through some user actions inside the view to change your model. Maybe this helps you a bit. There might be better ways ;)

Comment: In @pzaenger's response, "Main" is the controller, and "GUI" is the view.  Swing confuses the issue a bit, because most swing components serve both the view and the controller role in the MVC pattern. I often use the pattern he's describing, though--adding a separate model class which maintains app-wide preferences and view state (e.g. screen position and window size). Be clear with yourself on GUI's role: is it view and controller, or just view? In this model, it's just view. Same with anything you embed in GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Well for me(JavaFX):

I like to show user at the start of the application that something is actually going on in the background so ofcourse:Preloader is a must, in a code i load all the necessery data/access database/prepare application preferences and then INITIALIZE CONTROLLER/VIEW.

I do use multiple methods to go thru this process in my main.Breaking initialization into multiple parts.

I see view as a last to-do thing at application startup.

Javafx has a good structure which forces you to not MESS UP, you go thru linear path of initialization.I use  main controller,and subcontrollers.Main controller is initialized with parameters almost every time as needed,same goes for subcontrollers when they are not defined inside fxml.

(I keep one to one relationship-each fxml file(view) has its own controller,additionaly sometimes model when data have to be taken and separated from controller logic)

I use multiple models for some shared data between controllers (same structure main model/sub models)

I think in swing you have to be more carefull of how exactly you go thru your UI initialization process when you dont have fxml with defined controllers for instance.

Another thing i like to do is to have static acess from main method to all ma main controllers/models where i can directly access many important parts of my code.

These are the things that i do , that make me avoid Sphagetti code.
I learned my lessons from swing where i feel like im trying to BRUTE FORCE MVC into my design and then fail to understand my code.

I hope any of this helps you.At the end in my opinion there is no ONLY ONE CORRECT WAY of doing things.Personal preferences,technology that you use, type of software you create, all are the factors in this.

Comment: Great post. Thank you. Unfortunately I don't get to design advanced user interfaces so JavaFX is a bit far away from me. My question was more based on a simple swing GUI and what might be the right way to call that GUI from the main. I understand from your comment that there is no right way of doing it. Thank you.

Comment: @Noneedname Ask yourself what is more readable,for small application just initialize in main via some private static methods,complex systems will have different process and so on.Most important thing is  that you and people who read your source core understand what is happening.For my small programs i used class initialization cause it made more sense for me.I woud recommend you to find some good book on software design/architecture and start to read ;) Even if its not directly aimed for  guis, you will still benefit from advices there and these problems will make much more sense.